# Java program, int i (i=0) default value is being used despite it increasing by 1 each loop

Tags: java

I am creating a JAVA program to copy certain folders to a new location automatically, to do this I created a function with a loop to use the same function for each given folder source and destination. The problem is that the function will just copy the first folder to the new location multiple times instead of copying it once then copying the next folder. The folder locations are held in a string array and a specific one is selected by changing value `[i]`. Each time the function loops `[i]` increases but the loop does not select the `[i]` value as well as the next folder to copy.

Is anyone able to help me with this, the code i am working with is below, Thanks.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class Application {

static String[] saves = {
        "C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Documents\\My Games\\Halo",
        "C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Documents\\My Games\\Terraria",
        "C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Documents\\My Games\\Borderlands 2",
        "C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Documents\\My Games\\Rocket League"
};

private static int i = 1;

File source = new File(saves[i]);

static File folder = new File("Saves\\");

File dest = new File(String.valueOf(folder) + "\\" + source.getName());

private void Start() throws IOException {
    MakeDirectory(folder);
    Copy();
}

private void Copy() throws IOException {
    copyFileUsingJava7Files(source, dest);
    Add();
}

private void Add() throws IOException {
    i++;
    System.out.println("Value of i = " + i);
    System.out.println("");
}

private static void copyFileUsingJava7Files(File source, File dest)
        throws IOException {

    if (!dest.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Copying files from: " + "'" + source + "'");
        System.out.println("");
        copyFolder(source, dest);

        System.out.println("File copied");
    } else {
        copyFolder(source, dest);
    }
}

private static void copyFolder(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    if (source.isDirectory()) {
        if (!dest.exists()) {
            dest.mkdir();
            System.out.println("Directory created :: " + dest);
        }

        String files[] = source.list();
        for (String file : files) {
            File srcFile = new File(source, file);
            File destFile = new File(dest, file);

            copyFolder(srcFile, destFile);
        }
    } else {
        if (source.lastModified() > dest.lastModified()) {
            Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            System.out.println("File copied :: " + dest);
        } else {
            System.out.println("A newer version exists of: " + "'" + dest + "'");
        }
    }
}

private static void MakeDirectory(File folder) {

    if (!folder.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Creating directory: " + "'" + folder + "'");
        folder.mkdir();

        System.out.println("Directory created");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Directory already exists: " + "'" + folder + "'");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Application app = new Application();

    int l;
    for (l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
        app.Start();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just a note. Name methods with non-capital letter :)

Comment: ye I've been told that, I should really get into the habit of doing it, thank you :)

Comment: Not sure I understand the need for static methods / variables.

Comment: The way you are mixing static and non-static fields is very unsettling.  Also, this type of question is easily resolved by taking the time to step through the code line by line.

Comment: Also, please do follow the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're ever changing the `source` field after setting it initially. You're setting it to the second file, but then not changing it later. Incrementing `i` won't automatically update `source` because `source` is just a `File`.

Also, you're starting with `i = 1`. In Java, arrays are zero-indexed, which means that the first item in the array is actually item `0`, so you should be starting with `i = 0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinitialize `File source` each time, you increase i. Otherwise, the `source` won't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Since i is a static variable, all objects share the same variable. Since you are incrementing the i during each app.Start() method, at the end of calling 5 times, its value is 5. Consequently you get the output as 5 in all your sys outs. Thats the point of static.